# How to get all the metadata that have the same name from a python package?

Tags: python, python-importlib

I want to read metadata from a python package to feed a table withsome informations. The package is build using setuptools so all urls are saved under the `[project.urls]` field in the pyproject.toml file.

My problem is that when using `importlib` from a python script I only get the first one:

```
from importlib import metadata
metdata.metdata("pandas")["Project-URL"] # using pandas as an example
>>> 'homepage, https://pandas.pydata.org'
```

When in fact there are 3 of them:

```ini
[project.urls]
homepage = 'https://pandas.pydata.org'
documentation = 'https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/'
repository = 'https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas'
```

Is there a way to get all these metadata as a dict or at least a list that I can parse ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the result of the method is a Message object.This object have a `get_all` method dedicated to this use case:

```py
from importlib import metadata

metadata.metadata("pandas").get_all("Project-URL")

>>> ['homepage, https://pandas.pydata.org',
     'documentation, https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/',
     'repository, https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas']
```